# How to navigate to sections in different pages

Tags: html, sections, page-jump

Hello thank you for your time in advance. I am trying to navigate to section in home page from another .html page.  My problem is that it always jumps to top of the page no matter which section I specify.

Code in index.html (home/main page for features)

```
        <section id="features" class="s-features target-section">
```

Code in "other".html page

```
        <nav class="header-nav-wrap">
            <ul class="header-main-nav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#features">Features</a></li>
```

The main page uses a class="smoothscroll" if that may be causing issues or is helpful.
Thank you very much for your time and patience.

Comment: Hello. Can you tell us what plugin you are using for smooth scrolling? because your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Hero, however after removing the smooth scrolling feature I am still just being directed to the home page.  The URL does register my section call but the page does not follow this.